# iphone not detected on Android Studio (Flutter)

Tags: android, xcode, android-studio, flutter

Suddenly, my iphone 6s is no longer detected by Android studio Flutter while it shows on Xcode.

What could be the possible cause?

PS: It detects my Android phone.

Comment: Can you update your question with flutter doctor and try restarting android Studio

Comment: It seems i have to update my Xcode to latest version.